# Get value counts for a column in pandas. Receiving error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I imported a csv into pandas and have a dataframe like:

```
pd.DataFrame({'city': ['New York', 'Miami', 'Miami'], 
          'state': ['New York', 'Florida', 'Florida'],
          'country': ['USA', 'USA', 'USA']})
```

I want to write the following code:

```
df.city.value_counts().sum()
```

and get an output of:

```
New York 1
Miami 2
```

The error I receive is: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

How can I fix this error so I can do value counts? I know tuples are immutable, but I'm just importing a regular csv file, I've never seen this issue before.

Comment: Did you set `df`? e.g. `df =pd.DataFrame(....)` and then just do `df.city.value_counts()`

Comment: Yes, I did, here is an update. This code DOES work `df['city'].value_counts()` I am very confused why I can't use dot notation here? I checked the column names and there are no spaces.

Comment: Did you assign "city" using dot notation anywhere in your code? (e.g. `df.city = (1,2,3)`). This is why I always recommend square brackets + strings over dot notation. My least favorite feature of `pandas`. Try: `print(df.city)` and see what pops out.

Comment: @CameronRiddell that's probably it. Good point. Yeah, generally brackets notation has many more benefits than dot (aside from type-ability).

Comment: You most likely have a variable called city, use bracket notation it's clearer and safer.

Comment: @manakin Yes this is the case! Thank you for the help!